# How Can i paginate a list of object of my models (Play Framework)?

Tags: java, web, playframework, pagination

I'm New in this framework!
I want to generate a paginator of my models to show my lits in the templates.

I'm Using Play-java, Ebean, scala.html templates.

**Thanks!**

I have this!

**Model:**

```
public static Finder<String,User> find = new Finder(
    String.class, User.class
);


public static  List<User> all(){
    return find.all();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class UserController extends Controller {

   public Result index() {
      return ok(list_users.render(User.all()));
   }
}
```

**View (list_user.scala.html)**

```
      <table>
             <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>  
                 </tr>
             </thead>           
              <tbody>                
                @for(user<- users){               
                   <tr>
                       <td>@user.getEmail()</td>
                       <td>@user.getName()</td>
                       <td>@user.getLastName()</td>
                  </tr>       
               }
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function which fetches a page given page configuration from the data source.

```
 public static PagedList<User> page(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
        return
            find.where()
                .ilike("first_name", "%" + filter + "%")
                .orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
                .fetch("*")
                .findPagedList(page, pageSize);
    }
```

Then define a Action which renders a template populated with objects

```
public Result list(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
        return ok(
            views.html.list.render(
                page(page, 10, sortBy, order, filter),
                sortBy, order, filter
            )
        );
    }
```

This [Complete code Sample](https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean-example) will give you more insite.